# Angular routing is not working with Cloudfront and S3

Tags: angular, http, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular 6 website hosted on S3 with S3 website hosting enabled. Also, I have a CloudFront distribution in front of it. 
I configured cloud front so that it redirects anything to index.html and responses with 200.

However, only "/" can be accessed using CloudFront. Other urls such as "/*" are not loading. Angular loads "/" this instead. As if angular sees only "/".

I added some code to log the url passed to angular and it turns out to be always "/".

Also, some other times "/*" urls don't even load "/" and I see this error on console "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

Do you guys have any idea what could be causing this?

S3 Settings
[image]

Cloud front behavior:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show us the cloudfront configuration specifically `Behaviors` settings.

Comment: @A.Khan Hi Khan, attached as requested. Thanks

Comment: `I configured cloud front so that it redirects anything to index.html` - Are you using Lambda@Edge to redirect requests to index.html? Can you also show us the Edit view of `Default` path pattern please.

Comment: @A.Khan I attached new info. Hopefully, this is what u are looking for.

Comment: I’m not sure about your hosting config stuff, but I’ll tell you that angular will load the base href on any of your urls if you don’t set it in your build. We also have this problem with our keycloak hosting and I just gave up and started using hash location strategy in my router module. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have seen some people doing it, but I just don't know what is wrong with my configs!

Comment: https://arrayofcode.com/deploy-angular-react-website-on-a-custom-domain-using-aws-s3-cloudfront-and-route-53/

Answer (score 44):

Please have a look at : [how to deploy react and angular apps to S3/Cloudfront](https://lucasfsantos.com/posts/deploy-react-angular-cloudfront/)

Have you created a custom behavior for 403 (Forbidden) and 404 (not found) responses?

Every time that someone does a request to your website, for example, www.yourwebsite.com/**routeuri**, note that this URI **routeuri** does not exist in your ORIGIN (which is S3 BUCKET), so your origin (S3 BUCKET) will return 403 response (Forbidden). So you should also added a custom error response for 403 status code, as shown in image below:

[image]

Please also make sure that your also added **index.html** as a **Default Root Object** in both **Cloudfront** and **S3 Bucket** as shown by images below:

[image: Cloudfront root object]
[image: s3 bucket]

I really recommend read official documentation to understand about CloudFront relationship with origin.

Answer (score 6):

In my case this could be solved by adding index.html as the 'error document' under 'static website hosting'. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too and I fix it adding a custom error response in the CloudFront settings:

[image]

This happens because when you configure the CloudFront to be the only available access for the S3 bucket and you search /something, cloudfront will try to return that file to the user browser. Now the bucket is private and is only accessible from the CF, so this will return 403 or 404 error.
To solve it, you need to return index.html when those errors happen.

Credits: https://lucasfsantos.com/posts/deploy-react-angular-cloudfront/